# MVC cached minified bundle does not invalidate after new release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, bundling-and-minification

Our ASP.NET MVC site uses CSS/JS bundling (System.Web.Optimization version 1.1.3). We experience a problem during our roll out process:

When I make the first request after a release (using address bar -> enter) I see a stale, locally cached version of my bundled files. The headers are:

[image: dev tools cache directives]

Instead of a 200 I want to have a 304 response which checks the actual file on the server before determining if a cached version can be served. Is there a way to do so without having to use a special command like ctrl-f5 or ctrl-r?

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

After that, you can put on top of your Controller to prevent caching. Example

```
[NoCache]
public HomeController : Controller
{
    // ....
}
```

Or just use this on top of your controller.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```